# How to capture from a DVB-T Stick to an AVI-File

Tags: c#, streaming, video-streaming, capture, audio-streaming

I have a DVB-T Stick and i can draw the live capture on the form with the DirectShow.NET-Framework and C#, but how I can record this to an AVI-File by click on a start button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/directxcapture.aspx) by Brian Low

Comment: DirectShow.Net comes with a sample called CapWMV that shows how to capture a stream to a WMV file (much like an AVI, each is just a wrapper around an encoded stream). Check out http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/about.html